# Vectors must be the same length error in Curve Fitting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm having problems in curve fitting my randomized data for the function

[image]

Here is my code

```
N = 100;
mu = 5; stdev = 2;
x = mu+stdev*randn(N,1);
bin=mu-6*stdev:0.5:mu+6*stdev;
f=hist(x,bin);
plot(bin,f,'bo'); hold on;

x_ = x(1):0.1:x(end); 
y_ = (1./sqrt(8.*pi)).*exp(-((x_-mu).^2)./8); 
plot(x_,y_,'b-'); hold on;
```

It seems like I'm having vector size problems since it is giving me the error

```
Error using plot
    Vectors must be the same length.
```

Note that I simplified y_ since mu and the standard deviation is known.

Plot:

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `x` with `x_` when you create `y`?

Comment: I tried replacing x_ to x in generating y_ but I don't see my curve in the plot.

Comment: `x_ = x(1):0.1:x(end); y_ = (1./sqrt(8.*pi)).*exp(-((x_-mu).^2)./8); plot(x_,y_,'b-');` works for me. Creates an increasing but concave down shape, from `(3.8, 0.168)` to `(4.75, 0.197)`. So I'm not sure exactly what your problem is. If you want to create the histogram and the curve on the same plot, add `hold on;` before creating the second plot.

Comment: I do see that concave down shape, but I think that's because of the first  plot. I don't see the curve that is being plotted by x_ and y_. I appended the current look of my plot as well as the latest code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all some adjustments to your question:

- You are not trying to do [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). What you are trying to do (in my opinion) is to overlay a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) on an histogram obtained by taking random points from the same distribution (A normal distribution with parameters `(mu,sigma)`). These two curve should indeed overlay, as they represent the same thing, only one is analytical and the other one is obtained numerically.
- As seen in the [hist documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html), `hist` is not recommended and you should use [histogram instead](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html)

### First step: Generating your random data

Knowing the distribution is the Normal distribution, we can use [MATLAB's random function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html) to do that :

```
N = 150;
rng('default') % For reproducibility
mu = 5;
sigma = 2;
r = random('Normal',mu,sigma,N,1);
```

### Second step: Plot the histogram

Because we don't just want a count of the elements in each bin, but a feel of the probability density function, we can use the `'Normalization'` `'pdf'` arguments

```
Nbins = 25;
f=histogram(r,Nbins,'Normalization','pdf');
hold on
```

Here I'd rather specify a number of bins than specifying the bins themselves, because you never know *in advance* how far from the mean your data is going to be.

[image: Histogram plot]

### Last step: overlay the probability density function over the histogram

The histogram being already consistent with a probability density function, it is sufficient to just overlay the density function:

```
x_ = linspace(min(r),max(r),100);
y_ = (1./sqrt(2*sigma^2*pi)).*exp(-((x_-mu).^2)./(2*sigma^2)); 
plot(x_,y_,'b-');
```

With `N = 150`

[image: N = 150]

With `N = 1500`

[image: N = 1500]

With `N = 150.000` and `Nbins = 50`

[image: Last one]

### If for some obscure reason you want to use old hist() function

The old `hist()` function can't handle normalization, so you'll have to do it by hand, by normalizing your density function to fit your histogram:

```
N = 1500;
% rng('default') % For reproducibility
mu = 5;
sigma = 2;
r = random('Normal',mu,sigma,1,N);
Nbins = 50;
[~,centers]=hist(r,Nbins);
hist(r,Nbins); hold on

% Width of bins
Widths = diff(centers);

x_ = linspace(min(r),max(r),100);
y_ = N*mean(Widths)*(1./sqrt(2*sigma^2*pi)).*exp(-((x_-mu).^2)./(2*sigma^2)); 
plot(x_,y_,'r-');
```

[image: BadHist]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Can this be done with the old hist() function? You are using the newer histogram() function.

Comment: @lambduh why do you want to use the old `hist` function?

Comment: I actually want to do it by hand rather than having it done automatically by the function. Thank you!